# how swap between two array values?

Tags: java

When user enter number 1 smaller than number 2 swap does not work,
but when number 1 is larger than number 2 it works.  I don't understand why this is occurring.  I would appreciate some suggestions or help.

```
package javaapplication36;

public class JavaApplication36 {
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        input(arr);
        System.out.println("Enter n1 :");
        int n1 = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter n2 : ");
        int n2 = s.nextInt();
        display(arr);
        int temp = 0;
        int index_a = index(arr, n1);
        int index_b = index(arr, n2);
        if (index(arr, n1) != -1 && index(arr, n2) != -1) {
            temp = arr[index_a];
            arr[index_a] = arr[index_b];
            arr[index_b] = temp;
        }
        for (int i : arr) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void display(int[] arr) {
        for (int i : arr) {

            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void input(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter number : " + (i + 1));
            arr[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static int index(int[] arr, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == n)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and could not find anything wrong. To make debugging this easier I recommend you populate your array using random numbers.

Create an instance of `Random`

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

And assign the output to your array variable.

```
arr = rand.ints(10,1,15).toArray();
```

The arguments to `rand.ints` are.

- 10 - the number of elements
- 1 - the start of the range of numbers
- 15 - the end of the range (not including that number)

So that call would generate 10 numbers from 1 to 14 inclusive.

One possibility for any problems could be duplicate numbers in your array and finding the correct one to swap.  But I was unable to reproduce the error.